# Can lightweight components like JPanels be displayed without a heavyweight component like a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to find out whether lightweight components like JPanels can be displayed without a heavyweight component like a JFrame. I would say no but I can't seem to find a definite answer.

Comment: "Heavyweight" in this context generally means "corresponds to an external resource such as a window-manager window"; if you have zero external resources at all, then *where* would you be displaying your lightweight components?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you don't like the decorations of a JFrame then use a JWindow and it will appear like you only have a JPanel.

Comment: [*Using Top-Level Containers*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) is pretty definite: "To appear onscreen, every GUI component must be part of a…a tree of components that has a top-level container as its root."

Comment: So a top-level component must always exist in order to create a GUI component and since the only top-level components are JFrame,JApplet and JDialog, JPanel can't exist independently.  Is this correct?

Comment: Also to add onto my previous comment, is a JWindow a top-level container?